# Передача объектов по ссылке в Java

Tags: java, объекты

```
public class Human {
    final private String name;
    private Object age;

    public Human(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }


    public Object getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + name + ", age: " + age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Human human = new Human("George", 40);
        System.out.println(human);

        Object age = human.getAge();
        age = 50;
        System.out.println(human);



    }
}
```

На выходе получаю

```
name: George, age: 40
name: George, age: 40
```

Если age - это Object, то он должен передаваться по ссылке.
Когда я делаю `Object age = human.getAge()`, то в переменную `age` должна записываться ссылка на Object. Соответственно, `Object age` и `human.age` должны смотреть на один и тот же адрес памяти.
Почему, перезаписывая локальную переменную `age`, в объекте `human` остается старое значение `age`?

Comment: я понимаю так: объявляя переменную age, я создаю еще одну переменную в стэке. В ней хранится ссылка на тот же самый объект, т.е. ссылка в данный момент хранится два раза. А перезаписывая значение age = 50, где-то в куче создается еще один объект, и теперь age хранит новую ссылку. А старая ссылка human.age и старый объект как были, так и остались

Comment: Да, age хранит новую ссылку.

Answer (score 2):

Тут у вас путаница с контекстами выполнения. Переменная age внутри метода Main не имеет отношения к переменной внутри объекта. Вы действительно записываете в age новое значение, но human.age и Main#age имеют разные адреса в пямяти.

Answer (score 0):

Java передает все по значению.
https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/857-peredacha-parametrov-v-java

Comment: да, понятно. Думаю, ответ который даёт понимание картины: в humage.age и Main#age хранятся ссылки на один и то тот же объект, но после переприсваивания Main#age = 50 в куче создаётся еще один объект, и теперь Main#age будет ссылаться на этот новый объект, а human.age так и останется прежним